# WPF Datagrid doubleclick on row to enable the row for editing and leaving row should disable it

Tags: wpf, datagrid, mouseevent, wpfdatagrid

I want an example of `Style`s (or `Template`s) for a WPF `DataGrid` which will capture double click event on the `DataGrid` row and make it editable. When user leaves the row it should again get back to normal form (i.e. non editable)

One way that this could be done is via event handling in my view (code behind). However, that is not accepted as per MVVM principles. So I want ways to do this via Styles (or templates).

Comment: If its view specific code behind it does not break MVVM principals, having code behind tha modifies Data breaks MVVM, but code behind that simply changes properties on controls in the view then your MVVM pattern is still safe. MVVM does not mean no C# code

Comment: Hi,I will appreciate if you can point me to an example for this. thanks